# Excel - Search for a string then add some values (Entered to many arguments)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have  5 sheets with country data, I want to lookup the country name on 4 separate sheets within 4 separate ranges then take a value from the row and add all those values.

I was getting #NA as a return value so I added IFNA() to each lookup function which results in "To many arguments" error.

here is what the current state looks  like

```
=(SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4,Nation2017,2),0),IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4,Nation20018,2),0),IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4,Nation2016,2),0,),IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4,Nation2015,2),0))
```

Any help is  much appresiated

apologises I should have mentioned the Nation20018 misspelling isn't the issue I misspelt it and never corrected it

EDIT: I'll leave the question open as none of the suggested solutions did the job I did it manually at the end which was tedious, to say the least.

Comment: The first and easiest thing to check when you get an error like that is to count the total opening and closing brackets. You'll notice in your case that they do not match.

Comment: The second argument to your second `VLOOKUP` is `Nation20018`. Perhaps you meant ``Nation2018``?

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming that `Nation2015` & others are Named Range.**

*Instead of modify the existing Formula I would like to suggest a simple Formula using `CONCATENATE` to get Country Name from 4 separate sheets within 4 separate ranges and to add them to make one value.*

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(A4,Nation2017,2,FALSE)&" "&(VLOOKUP(A4,Nation2018,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A4,Nation2016,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A4,Nation2015,2,FALSE)))
```

- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.
- Check `Nation20018` I also guess, it should be `Nation2018` instead.